# Telegram окно которое убирается свайпом

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Такой вопрос, в telegram при открытии функций (допустим открыть настройки) на весь экран появляется, что на подобии DialogFragment на весь экран, которое можно убрать свайпом, так у меня такой вопрос, может эта какая-то специальная библиотека, а если не это не так как реализовать закрытие диалогового окна свайпом как там?

[image: Картинка 1(открытое окно)]
[image: Картинка 2(закрытие окна)]

Comment: https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer оно?

Comment: Нет, я внес попраку о том что имею ввиду